# How to return ajax success json array in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function add_to_cart(product_id,sub_product_id,period,type,description){
    var product_id=product_id;
    var sub_product_id=sub_product_id;
    var period=period;
    var type=type;
    var description=description;
    var add_to_cart="YES";
        $.ajax({
        url:'libraries/ajax.php',
        data:{
                product_id:product_id,
                sub_product_id:sub_product_id,
                period:period,
                type:type,
                description:description,
                add_to_cart:add_to_cart,

                },
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data){



            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            return obj;

            }
        });
}
var returnValue = add_to_cart(2,sub_pro_id,1,"HOSTING",description);
alert(returnValue.return_value);
```

call Return object from array
How do I return ajax success json array in function? I want to get return json array and call like above

Comment: what do you want to do with the `success` object? Pass it to a function?

Comment: yes i want add_to_cart() return me the json success data

Comment: You cannot return something from an asynchronous call

Comment: is there any way to return

Comment: You either use a callback or return a promise.